# How to filter DIV Content on keyup

Tags: jquery

I have a Search Box under which user types in. On this event I am trying to show only the relevant results present under div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#trainername').keyup(function() {
        var tr = $('.trainers_listWrap li');
        if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
            var inputdata = $.trim($("#trainername").val());

            var noElem = true;
            var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
            el = tr.filter(function() {
                return $(this).find('.mt-radio').text().toLowerCase().match("^" + val);
            });
            if (el.length >= 1) {
                noElem = false;
            }
            tr.not(el).fadeOut();
            el.fadeIn();
        } else {
            tr.fadeIn();
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<div class="modal-content">
    <form id="trainerinsertform" name="trainerinsertform" class="form-horizontal bv-form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <button type="submit" class="bv-hidden-submit" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></button>
        <div class="modal-body addTrainerContainer">
            <section class="addTrainer_search">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <span id="errmsgtrainer"></span>
                    <div class="form-group last">
                        <input type="text" id="trainername" name="trainername" value="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20" class="form-control" data-bv-field="trainername">
                        <small class="help-block" data-bv-validator="notEmpty" data-bv-for="trainername" data-bv-result="NOT_VALIDATED" style="display: none;">Trainer Name cannot be empty</small><small class="help-block" data-bv-validator="stringLength"
                        data-bv-for="trainername" data-bv-result="NOT_VALIDATED" style="display: none;">Please enter a value with valid length</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="trainers_listWrap">
                <li>
                    <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline traine">
                        <input type="radio" data-value="One" class="trainerradio" value="15" name="One">One
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline traine">
                        <input type="radio" data-value="Two" class="trainerradio" value="1" name="Two">Two
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline traine">
                        <input type="radio" data-value="Three" class="trainerradio" value="23" name="Two">Two
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline traine">
                        <input type="radio" data-value="Four" class="trainerradio" value="10" name="Two">Two
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                </li>
            </section>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/368/

Could you please tell me how to resole this

Comment: You have invalid HTML, `li` must be inside `ul` or `ol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want?
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/372/)

Removed `"^"` from your `.find()`
Removed `var inputdata` since it's not used.
Fixed HTML-syntax